# Tab align in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, tabs

I would like to have some dates and some description on the same line. However, I'd like the dates (which appear first) to align right and end at .75" from the left margin. Then the description would be aligned left but would start 1" from the left margin.

I've been trying to play around with tabs with no luck. I've done the flush left and flush right on the same line before, but it was always with first text flushed left and what follows flushed right.  Any tips for the opposite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NB: I *think* this is what you want.

See the little "L" shaped icon near the top right (next to the arrow in my screen cap:
[image]

This is the alignment of tabs

Click on it once, it becomes an upside down "T"

[image]

Again and it becomes a mirrored "L"

[image]

(There are other icons but these are the three I'll focus on, keep clicking to loop through them)

Each of these icons represents the alignment of tabs. Have the one you want active and click on the ruler at the top of your document. The location will determine where tabs align:

[image]